# C# SQL connection parameters login

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, parameters, sqlconnection

I'm still a beginner, I'm going to do some "inserts", I want 'Server, data, User, Pass" information to input "textbox" for the SQL used. for me to insert accordingly. how can I connect the link chain "texbox" below?

`Source=" + Server.Text + "` it didn't work that way

```
namespace SQL_ParametreTest1 
{
    public partial class Form1: Form 
    {
        public Form1() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string connectionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;

        connectionString = @ "Data Source=" + Server.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + Data.Text + ";User ID=" + User.Text + ";Password=" + Pass.Text + "";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile? If not what are the errors?

Comment: You shouldn't cache the connection object, by the way. Just create a new connection when you need it from the connection string, and dispose with `using`

Answer (score 2):

This is too soon. The user hasn't had a chance to fill in those textboxes yet.

Even worse, `cnn` and `connectionString` are classified as "derived instance fields", which means they are initialized before the constructor is called<sup>1</sup>, which in turn means `InitializeComponent()` hasn't been called yet and the TextBox variables are all still `null`.

The solution is to wait until the point where the user wants to perform an action, *after* they've had a chance to actually put data into the textboxes.

Also, it's poor practice to try to re-use an `SqlConnection` object through an app or form<sup>2</sup>. It really will perform better if you create a new connection object for each query, and then dispose each connection immediately, typically with a `using` block.

---

<sub>1. https://www.csharp411.com/c-object-initialization/

2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/398790/8057</sub>